# Migration from gulp v3 to v4

Tags: gulp, gulp-task

I've tried to migrate from gulp v3 to v4, but when I write 'gulp build' I get such error

> D:\Projects\Exo\exo\src\COG.SRM\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10
>   assert(typeof fn === 'function', 'Task function must be specified');
>   ^ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must
>   be specified
>       at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (D:\Projects\Exo\exo\src\COG.SRM\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
>       at Gulp.task (D:\Projects\Exo\exo\src\COG.SRM\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
>       at Object. (D:\Projects\Exo\exo\src\COG.SRM\gulpfile.js:341:6)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
>       at execute (C:\Users\SS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18)

According to my researches, I should change my gulpfile.js file.

Could someone help me please how to change such commands according to the new version of gulp:

```
gulp.task('clean-css', function (cb) {
    return rimraf(paths.css, cb);
});

gulp.task('clean', ['clean-css', 'clean-fonts', 'clean-js']);

gulp.task('build-css', ['lint-css'], function () {});
```